# Column Line Chart using asp.net 3.5 chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have created a sample column chart using asp.net 3.5 (visual studio 2008) chart control by binding values from database.It is working. Now I want to show a line and column chart on y axis of same graph. Is it possible? I copied same code as like in the below link.But it shows nothing.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/viewCodeSnippet.jsp?codeSnippetId=20-40238814-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually put the Chart object onto the screen. A simple docking would do the trick.

```
chart.Parent = this; 
chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```